# Errors in a simple C++ program

Tags: 12.04, c++

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    char ch = 'A';
    int num = ch;

    cout << "The ASCII code for " << ch << "is " << num << "\n";
    cout << "Adding 1 to the character code : \n";
    ch = ch + 1;
    num = ch ;
    cout << "The ASCII code for " << ch << "is " << num << "\n";
    return (0);
}
```

I get the errors like

```
ex1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ex1.cpp:6:5: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
ex1.cpp:6:5: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:62:18: note:   ‘std::cout’
```

Guys please correct my mistakes.

Comment: Simply add 'using namespace std' before main function

Comment: You should ask programming related questions at [www.stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com), this website is only for Ubuntu-related questions. :) And the above comment is the answer to the question.

Comment: @green7 New to AskUbuntu so sorry :)

Comment: No Problem. Atleast, now you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **not** add a global `using namespace std` as other users are saying, this is an extremely bad practice, learn how to use methods and namespaces instead.

`cout` is not a particular method, `std::cout` is the method `cout` from the `std` namespace and this is the correct way to write methods in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Add `using namespace std` after your include(s).

Comment: Whoops.. Just realized the answer already was in the comments above.

Comment: I posted it as comment because this question is offtopic here

Comment: Fair enough! It might get moved anyway.